# How to find the inverse of a Rectangular Matrix in C using GSL

Tags: c, gsl, matrix-inverse

I searched on Google and I couldn't find a function to calculate the inverse of Rectangular Matrix using GSL. Being that it was hard to find, an answer here would help others when they need to find an inverse of a rectangular matrix.
If it is not possible using GSL, then please suggest some alternative library which is easy to use and provides the inverse of rectangular matrix.

Comment: You can apply [SVD](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Singular-Value-Decomposition.html) and then calculate the pseudoinverse, as suggested in for example the [R documentation](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/corpcor/html/pseudoinverse.html)

Comment: There's an SVD solver in the GSL, and then it's just matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible! You probably did not fin it because it is in the chapter Linear Algebra, not Matrices.

In GSL you first compute the LU decomposition and then use it to determine the inverse via

**int** *gsl_linalg_LU_invert* (const gsl_matrix * LU, const gsl_permutation * p, gsl_matrix * inverse)

See here for a detailed example
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gsl/2008-11/msg00001.html

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/LU-Decomposition.html

Comment: In the [example](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gsl/2008-11/msg00001.html) cited, the original matrix a_data is modified after calculating its inverse. Is there a way to avoid this issue ?  @Ludi